# squeeze theorem and 3 variable function's limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y,z) = \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. Its limit at $(0,0,0)$ is $0$ and we had to prove it. My TA in tutorial did  it this way:
$\left|\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|\leq  \frac{x^2+y^2+|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

and since $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq 1$
so,
  $\frac{x^2+y^2+|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\leq|xyz|$ which tends to $0$ at $(0,0,0)$
so limit is $0$.

But isn't this wrong? Shouldn't this work out only if $x^2+y^2$ and $|xyz|$ were multiplied to each other? Can someone tell me what should be the correct method.

Comment: @kronos Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right that the TA was in error. He confused multiplication and addition.

You most definitely do *not* need to think about spherical coordinates. (Generally, people on MSE resort to polar coordinates and spherical coordinates when it's not necessary.) Note that the key idea is that
$$|x|, |y|, |z|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$
(and this works in however many dimensions you wish). So
$$0\le \frac{|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \le \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},$$
and now we can easily apply the squeeze theorem to deduce the limit is $0$.

Comment: It's a nice solution and I've also added a derivation by AM-GM. Anyway I do not agree with your suggestion to refuse spherical coordinates (or polar when they need to be used) since many times they are very useful and powerful to solve thise kind of limits. Solutions by inequalities are very nice and elegant but not always they are easy to be handled and can lead to mistakes (as did the TA in this case). Thus I prefer suggest also spherical/polar coordinates as a very good and simpler method which do not exclude to solve the limit also by others methods such as inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right the solution given is wrong, by inequality we can proceed as shown bt Ted Shifrin or as an alternative by AM-GM

$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{(xyz)^2}\implies |xyz|\le\frac{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}}{3\sqrt{3}}<(x^2+y^2+z^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

then

$$\left|\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|=  \frac{|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2}<\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to 0$$

Inequality are of course a good and very elegant method to proceed but not always those way are simple to handle (indeed your TA made a mistake).

Thus as a good alternative we can also solve by spherical coordinates

- $x=r\sin \phi \cos \theta$
- $y=r\sin \phi \sin \theta$
- $z=r\cos \phi$

for $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to 0$ we have

$$\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=r\cdot f(\theta,\phi) \to 0$$

since $f(\theta,\phi)=\sin^2 \phi\cos \phi \cos \theta\sin \theta$ is bounded.